# Speaker-dependent Voice Recognition

Tags: arduino-uno

I would like to install speaker-dependent voice recognition in a robot equipped with Arduino Uno compatible boards.
Specifically, I want to record the robot's name beforehand and have it respond when I call the robot's name.

Although it is not an Arduino, there is a person who has developed a function that I would like to realize with the M5StickV.
This person used [isolated_word.py](https://github.com/sipeed/MaixPy_scripts/tree/master/multimedia/speech_recognizer), a library published by Sipeed, as a reference.

[【K210】マイク搭載版M5StickV,Sipeed Maixシリーズで音声認識をする](https://raspberrypi.mongonta.com/isorated-word-recognizer-k210/)

After some research, I found [Maix_Speech_Recognition](https://github.com/sipeed/Maixduino/tree/master/libraries/Maix_Speech_Recognition) in the library of Maixduino, which can use Arduino IDE.
Apparently, it uses Mel-frequency cepstrum coefficients analysis of speech input, and then uses dynamic time stretching to find the similarity.
The MFCC uses the K210 FFT on the Maixduino.

Arduino Uno does not have an FFT accelerator, but it can do FFT.
Therefore, I thought it would be possible to use Maix_Speech_Recognition for specific speaker speech recognition on ArduinoUno compatible devices.

**Question**

1. Is it possible to use Maix_Speech_Recognition for speaker-dependent voice recognition on Arduino Uno compatible boards?
2. What part of Maix_Speech_Recognition should I modify to make it work on Arduino Uno compatible boards?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? I doubt the UNO has enough processing power for voice recognition, but I might be wrong.

Comment: The UNO has *way* too little RAM to do an FFT big enough to be useful for this... only 2K.  And since it doesn't have a math coprocessor in hardware to compute all the trig factors on the fly, it would have to store those in the same limited RAM space or else your FFT would slow to a crawl.  I think you should consider another approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Maix_Speech_Recognition for speaker-dependent voice recognition on Arduino Uno compatible boards?

No. It's not.

> What part of Maix_Speech_Recognition should I modify to make it work on Arduino Uno compatible boards?

Don't even think about it. The UNO *cannot* do anything even remotely like speech recognition of any form without adding extra specific speech recognition hardware.

Just get a K210 board - they're cheap enough.